# Regular expressions matching too many sets of parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I am using regular expressions in python to extract data elements from a text file. I am running into a problem with grabbing too many sets of parentheses.

The text is stored in a string named temp and is of the form:

```
temp='Somethingorother School District (additional text)|other stuff here'
```

I am currently using

```
match = re.search(r'(.* School District) (\(.*\))\|?',temp)
```

Which works great and matches

```
match.group(1) = Somethingorother School District
match.group(2) = (additional text)
```

However, sometimes the 'other stuff here' part also contains parentheses, like this:

```
'Somethingorother School District (additional text)|$59900000 (4.7 mills)'
```

so I get

```
match.group(2) = (additional text)|$59900000 (4.7 mills)
```

I understand that this is because the * operator is greedy, but the (additional text) part is rather idiosyncratic and I want to capture whatever is in those parentheses. In other words, I want it to be greedy within those parentheses, but then stop looking once it matches a ). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Best way is to replace `.*` by `[^)]*` which will match anything but closing `)` and so will make it stop matching when you encounter the first `)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

```
>>> match = re.search(r'(.* School District) (\([^()]*\))\|?',temp)
>>> match.group(1)
'Somethingorother School District'
>>> match.group(2)
'(additional text)'
```

`[^()]*` matches any character but not of `(` or `)` zero or more times.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pO2sU3/2)

Answer (score 1):

Put non greedy on the last parentheses.